# why indexer are known as smart array in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm totally new to programming and I am wondering; when would be a good time
to use an array or an indexer? I want to know what types of applications
would make good use of arrays or indexers. There seems to be other ways of
doing the jobs of the two and less confusing.

The books I read don't provide good examples of situations when I would need
an array or indexer. I don't really need a definition of them as I already
have that. I just need to know what which well known apps have uses for
arrays and indexer?

Comment: Arrays are a data structure; indexers are a syntactic language feature.  Are you actually asking about `List<T>`?

Comment: Hint: How would you write a program that manages an address book?

Comment: no i asking about why indexer are known as smart array ?

Comment: can you explain with some example please..

Comment: This is the first time I've ever heard the term "smart array" in C#.

Comment: visit http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b56248f-1ff6-41aa-a0cd-35735e802e13/what-is-indexer-for-in-c and read it

Comment: @user3288935: A forum post is hardly authoritative. I've rarely heard anybody referring to class with an indexer as a "smart array" rather than just a typed collection.

Comment: Nothing that ever gets posted to the MSDN forums is a proof of anything.  Indexers make a collection type *look* like an array.  You can call it a "smart array" if you like, it is just not common to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I think arrays are a pain to manage, and I don't use them very often. As a programmer, you have to be completely responsible for the length of an array.

```
string[] str1 = new string[10];
```

When you add and remove items from the array, you have to be aware of all times where in the array you are.

Personally I avoid arrays when possible and use strongly typed collection, like `List`

```
List<string> str1 = new List<string>();
```

Then I can use the built-in methods to manage the items without having to be as concerned with managing the fine details.

```
str1.Add("Hello!");
str1.Add("Hello again!");
str1.RemoveAt(0);
Console.WriteLine(str1[0]); //Hello again!
```

Comment: its concept of array and list i want why indexer are known as smart array in c#?

Comment: Again, indexers are NOT known as "smart arrays".  Exactly why that person claimed that they are I don't know but I've been using C# for over 10 years and never heard that term before.  To call an indexer a "smart array" would be stupid anyway.  An indexer is basically a property to allow you to access an item in a collection while an array is actually a data structure to hold the items themselves.  To call a collection a "smart array" might make some sense but the indexer of a collection is something else entirely.  You say that you understand what arrays and indexers are but I would say not.

Comment: It does not really make anything "smarter". It's simply a way to allow you to put an index on a class to reference objects in the class like you would in an array, with the `[]` bracket syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> This is the first time I've ever heard the term "smart array" in C#

**No one uses the phrase "smart array" not that I heard of.**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b56248f-1ff6-41aa-a0cd-35735e802e13/what-is-indexer-for-in-c

**no one calls [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)  smart array except the guy in the linked forum post.**

indexers used for stuff like [Dictionaries](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=_Bn3UvDWLOi07QbY44GoCw&usg=AFQjCNGx28LfFdtzmlSdjum4DfvoMRHwFQ&sig2=uO_mmmPjKJx6uxxetUIWog&bvm=bv.60983673,d.ZGU) and [Hashtables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Great. I've never heard of *smart arrays* either. But anyway, I don't think that copy/paste peace of text and code answers the question.

Comment: I disagree it does provide examples.

Comment: mr marcinjuraszek read msdn library about indexer in c#

Comment: @user3288935: I think he knows better than you for you to say that. And sure, MSDN calls them indexers... but where does it call them smart arrays?

Comment: @user3288935 I know what indexer in c# is, and how/when it should be used. Problem is, I've never heard anyone naming indexer *smart array*. And I don't think post on MSDN **forum** proves anything. I can easily add a post and name them anyway you wan't (and even say *it's common to use that name*. It does not mean people actually uses that name. And I'm pretty sure there's nothing about *smart array* in MSDN **documentation**.

Comment: ohk i agree with your answer .. can you tell me why indexer is better than array ?

Answer (score 0):

I think answer to *why indexer are known as smart array in c#?* question is **they are not.**

Post on MSDN **forum** does not prove anything. There is nothing about *smart array* on MSDN **documentation**. You should follow official feature naming, which is **indexer** or **indexed property**. That's the name you can find on

- Specification: chapter *10.9 Indexers*

  > An **indexer** is a member that enables an object to be indexed in the same way as an array. Indexers are declared using *indexer-declarations*:
- Documentation: [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

  > Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.